# HTML type="date" and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, date

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="l-dbDetails"> 
    <label>Start Date: </label>
    <input type="date" id="l-StartDate" name="StartDate" value="2017-04-03" size="29px" class="l-required" required=""><br>
</div>
```

This gives me a nice date picker field in which I can choose a date.

I then need to get the date from this field using jQuery, so I use:

```
startDate = $('#l-StartDate').attr('value');
```

But this always returns the default value of "2017-04-03". How can I make jQuery pick up the new date?

Comment: `$('#l-StartDate').val()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I use ...`attr('value')`

The current value of an input isn't its `value` attribute. To get the current value with jQuery, use `.val()`, not `.attr('value')`:

```
startDate = $('#').val();
```

The value will be a string.

On modern browsers with up-to-date handling for `type="date"` inputs, you can also use the underyling [`HTMLInputElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmlinputelement)'s `valueAsDate` property:

```
startDate = $('#l-StartDate').prop("valueAsDate");
```

Example:

```js
$("#l-StartDate").on("change", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log("String: ", $this.val());
  console.log("Date: ", $this.prop("valueAsDate"));
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="l-StartDate">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Details:

The `value` **attribute** controls the default value of the input, and doesn't change as the user changes the value. That attribute is reflected by the `defaultValue` property of the underlying `HTMLInputElement`. The *current* value is reflected by the `value` property of that input (which isn't stored as an attribute at all). jQuery's `val` accesses the `value` property of the `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: I don't know why I was doing that way (I'm sure it made sense at some point in time!!!). Cheers for the great explanation.